# How do computers know how to use TCP

Tags: networking, internet-connection, network-adapter, tcp, tcpip

I'm asking from a Windows perspective but any perspective is great.

Are NICs all a computer needs to interface with TCP? Wouldn't they also need some sort of software associated with TCP, or is that included in the NIC device drivers?

Comment: `How do computers know how to use TCP?` ... computers do not "know" anything ... everything that a computer does is controlled by a program that someone wrote

Comment: TCP/IP is these days part of the operating system.  But some cards are smart enough to do at least some of TCP/IP by itself, offloading some of the effort from the main CPU.   But unless you want a switch that just passes traffic, you need an OS to do anything interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for TCP/IP is built into the kernel. All the bits of software that implement the different networking protocols that layer on top of each other are called the "network stack".

So when your app calls the "[BSD] Sockets APIs" to do networking, it's invoking code that runs mostly in the kernel.

Some NICs can handle some parts of TCP/IP processing directly in NIC hardware, offloading some of the work so it doesn't have to be handled by the kernel on the CPU. These are called "TCP Offload Engines", or sometimes specific types of offloads have their own names, like "hardware checksumming", "Large Receive Offload" (LRO), "Transmit Segmentation Offload" (TSO), etc. The kernel's network stack has to support letting this stuff be handled by the NICs, and the NIC drivers have to support telling the kernel what the NIC can handle, and telling the NIC to do it if that's what the kernel requests. But the drivers themselves don't do much of the real work, because drivers run in the kernel, and so it wouldn't really offload anything from the CPU if a NIC driver in the kernel was doing it instead of the normal network stack in the kernel.

In some cases it can be more efficient to move some of the functions of the network stack out of the kernel and into "user space" (i.e. implemented by OS-provided libraries that run in the application context, not in the kernel context). This can improve efficiency by not having to copy packet data between application memory and kernel memory as often. So some parts of the network stack can now be found outside the kernel, in user space. But it's still provided by the OS's built-in networking libraries.

Comment: More information on the Windows tcp/ip stack>>>>>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock